# How do I stop doorkeeper from redirecting, and instead show me the oauth/authorize view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I'm currently working on an integration in our application for IFTTT.  I've got doorkeeper set up and authorizing.

I'm running into an issue where when the user hits the oauth/authorize route, doorkeeper is automatically redirecting back to the client application.  In every example I've seen, doorkeeper shows a view asking the user to authorize {application name here} with our app.  That's not happening for me. It's just redirecting back to the client redirect_uri. I'm not really even sure how to search for this so if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.